# checkbox select/deselect in repeater when click on text

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, repeater

say we have simple asp.net repeater, 
in a row we have one checkbox, one label (database-id of the record) and not visible (used for postback) and one text (in a tabelcell)

now i want to make it like in windows, if you click on the text, the checkbox should be selected or deselected.

has somebody a link or solution for this, maybe already with jQuery?

Edit: as i said, it is a asp.repeater. and the table is for layout, so using the checkbox.text property is not designable (e.g. line wrap)
the ids of the checkbox and text are dynamically added/changed on rendering of the repeater. therefore the label solution does also not really work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

assume that you wont't need jQuery and the table-construct

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text="your text" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

this renders basically the solution provided by Ricardo Vega
whatever you get in the property text of the checkbox is clickable, and checks/unchecks the checkbox ... therefor you should use <%# Eval("...") %>
you can skin (via css) the margin of the label

**Edit:**

After thinking about this once again, there is another solution:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:Checkbox runat="server" ID="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="checkbox">Your text</asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Notes: You can use the Text-attribute of the asp:Label-Element either!

Comment: Good answer, sorry answering without ASP knowledge. Maybe is better to use the simplest approach instead of adding a layer of complexity.

Comment: Sooooooo glad I don't work with ASP ;) But +1 for not using javascript.

Answer (score 4):

maybe I don't understand completely but why don't you use the html attribute "for" in the label tag?

Like:

```
<label for="field_id">Checkbox 1</label>
<input id="field_id" type="checkbox" />
```

And that will make the checkbox act as clicked if the label is clicked. So you don't have to depende on JS to do this.

Edit:
If you really really want to use jQuery for this:

```
$('td').click(function(){
  $(':checkbox',this).attr('checked',!$(':checkbox',this).attr('checked'));
});
```

Change 'td' as needed.

Comment: maybe the checkbox needs to be an asp-control to get the check-state. therefor the clientid will be dynamically rendered and can't be used inside the itemtemplate for the label

Answer (score 1):

If you go with one of the jQuery click solutions make sure you ignore click events triggered by the checkbox itself.

```
$('td').click(function(e){
    if (!$(e.target).is(':checkbox')) { // toggle only on non-checkbox click
        var checked = $(':checkbox', this).attr('checked');
        $(':checkbox', this).attr('checked', !checked); // toggle
    }
});
```

Comment: didn't take that into account in my solution +1

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
$('.yourtableclass td').click( function( e ) {
    var cb = $(this).children('input[type=checkbox]').get(0);
    cb.checked = !cb.checked;
});
```